# How can I trigger a Mongodb import once a Scrapy Spider has completed?

Tags: python, mongodb, web-scraping, scrapy, upsert

I am using Scrapy, the Python library, to scrape websites and generate json output files at regular intervals.
For efficiency, I want to do bulk upserts of these json files into Mongodb after each spider is completed.

I believe I can do the upsert like so:

```
mongoimport -c <collection> -d <db> --mode merge --file test.json
```

However, I am wondering what is the best way to to trigger this import once the spider has complete? And how?

I was hopeful I could use the close_spider method described here:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#writing-your-own-item-pipeline

However, after playing around with it I discovered that the json file is only created, and not written to when inside this method.

It would be nice if there was some way for me to listen for a new file in a certain directory and then execute the import statement above.

Perhaps, this can all be done in a bash script?s

Answer (score 0):

You could write items directly into Mongo using *Item Pipelines*. Take a look in this example, from the [Scrapy's documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#write-items-to-mongodb):

> ## Write items to MongoDB
>
> In this example we’ll write items to MongoDB using pymongo. MongoDB address and database name are specified in Scrapy settings; MongoDB collection is named after item class.
>
> The main point of this example is to show how to use from_crawler() method and how to clean up the resources properly.:
>
> ```
> import pymongo
>
> class MongoPipeline(object):
>
>     collection_name = 'scrapy_items'
>
>     def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
>         self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
>         self.mongo_db = mongo_db
>
>     @classmethod
>     def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
>         return cls(
>             mongo_uri=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
>             mongo_db=crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'items')
>         )
>
>     def open_spider(self, spider):
>         self.client = pymongo.MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
>         self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]
>
>     def close_spider(self, spider):
>         self.client.close()
>
>     def process_item(self, item, spider):
>         self.db[self.collection_name].insert_one(dict(item))
>         return item
> ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @Thiago. This approach, although common, is very slow and inefficient because it hammers the database and makes many round trips over the network. Hence the approach I'm using.

Answer (score 0):

This method works for me (in your spider file):

```
import os
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.xlib.pydispatch import dispatcher

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):

    def __init__(self):
        dispatcher.connect(self.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        os.system("your_command")
```

Comment: I put an inspect_response inside the spider_closed and saw that the file was created at that point but the data wasn't written so didn't go any further.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is use pyinotify to watch a file in the chosen directory. I got the idea from [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2010/04/monitoring-filesystem-python-and-pyinotify/) and adapted it to execute the mongo import statement.

```
class MyEventHandler(pyinotify.ProcessEvent):

    def process_IN_ACCESS(self, event):
        print("ACCESS event:", event.pathname)

    def process_IN_ATTRIB(self, event):
        print("ATTRIB event:", event.pathname)

    def process_IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE(self, event):
        print("CLOSE_NOWRITE event:", event.pathname)

    def process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE(self, event):
        print("CLOSE_WRITE event:", event.pathname)
        result = os.system('mongoimport -c kray4 -d kray4 --mode merge --file /home/kevin/PycharmProjects/spider/krawler/output/test.json')
        print("Result: " + str(result))

    def process_IN_CREATE(self, event):
        print("CREATE event:", event.pathname)

    def process_IN_DELETE(self, event):
        print("DELETE event:", event.pathname)

    def process_IN_MODIFY(self, event):
        print("MODIFY event:", event.pathname)

    def process_IN_OPEN(self, event):
        print("OPEN event:", event.pathname)


def main():
    # watch manager
    wm = pyinotify.WatchManager()

    wm.add_watch('/home/kevin/PycharmProjects/spider/krawler/output/test.json', pyinotify.ALL_EVENTS, rec=True)

    # event handler
    eh = MyEventHandler()

    # notifier
    notifier = pyinotify.Notifier(wm, eh)
    #command = 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'
    notifier.loop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```